# How would i check if a column in my sql table is null using c#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have a method which checks returns true/false depending on if a column is null or not in a sql table.

How would i go about checking if a certain column is null in my sql db in my c# method.

```
public bool CheckQuoteStatus(string user)
{
    //checking against the sql db in table where userid=user if column
      QUOTESTATUS=NULL then return false otherwise return true

}
```

here is how im connecting to the sql db

```
static SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ToString());
```

Comment: What are you using to connect to the database? Null can be returned in different ways based on the framework you're using.

Comment: edited my question, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the value is returned from a query, you can against null value using `DbNull.Value`

```
return (user == DbNull.Value ? true : false);
```

Comment: how would i query and hold the result in a variable?

Comment: this is identical to return user == DbNull.Value btw :P. The ternary isn't needed

Comment: :p it should be the other way round `return(user == DbNull.Value ? false : true);`